# sql get specific time in date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, time

I want to write a SQL query to return results from 9PM yesterday until the current time.  As far as I know, `GETDATE()` will only give me today's results, and `GETDATE()-1` will give me all of yesterday, which I don't want.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from tbl
where datecol between dateadd(hour,21,DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()-1))
  and getdate()
```

Comment: Why BETWEEN? Isn't `datecol >= ...` sufficient?

Comment: @Joe - It may be an calendar table with future data. Not specified

Comment: @dj18 There are bottom dwellers on SO as on every other site. You could vote it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24-9 HOUR);
```

This substracts 24-9 hours to the current date, which is equivalent to substracting 1 day and adding 9 hours.

Comment: @user576875 given that GETDATE() is used in the question, I think the OP is looking SQL Server syntax not MySQL

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this works perfectly in Sybase databse

**select * from table where datecol > dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(hour,18,(convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))))**

Explanation: (Inside to outside)

1. convert(date, getdate()) -- This will get the today's date with only date part i.e., 7/19/2015
2. convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())) -- This will get the today's date with time as 00:00 hours i.e., 7/19/2015 12:00:00 AM
3. dateadd(hour,21,(convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))) -- This will add the hours to previously obtained result i.e., 7/19/2015 9:00:00 PM
4. dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(hour,18,(convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))))) -- Finally this will minus one day for the obtained date i.e., 7/18/2015 9:00:00 PM

Here you go...